# Disabling submit button cancels form submit

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="lol.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="fe" />
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="submit" onclick="this.disabled = true;" />
</form>
```

and in Firefox it works perfectly, but in Internet Explorer (latest version) the button becomes disabled but the form does not submit. I have also tried:

```
<form action="lol.php" method="POST" onsubmit="document.getElementById('submitbtn').disabled = true">
```

and removed the onclick code from the submit button, but that had the same effect. What code should I use so that it works on all browsers?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so the good hack is to prepare second fake button that does nothing:

```
<form action="lol.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="fe" />
<input type="button" id="submitbtnDisabled" disabled="disabled" value="submit" style="display:none;" />
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="submit" onclick="this.style.display='none'; document.getElementById('submitbtnDisabled').style.display='inline';" />
</form>
```

Note:

Because you said you're not using jQuery I'm using standard JavaScript. The only suggestion is to use unbotrusive JavaScript and move inline CSS to a stylesheet just to separate scripts and styles from HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem before as well. I ended up hiding the submit button when the form was submitted, and replacing it with a disabled button with the same text. Worked great.

Comment: I might have to do that if nobody comes up with a non-hack way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
onclick="this.disabled=true;return true;"
```

Otherwise, MS explorer is not allowing the button to continue processing once disabled.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Clarification: it doesn't work if I leave the text fields empty. If they are filled, it works. This applies to any method I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird.

Try:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="submit" onclick="setTimeout(function () { this.disabled = true;}, 0)" />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want you can use jquery.

Try this:

```
$('#submtbtn').submit(function() {
   $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

I think it works on all browser.